Get Absolute Reference of an Element using Selenium
I am new in Selenium. I am creating a first example where I go to a website (https://mediamarkt.es) and then I search for an specific product. My code is able to get the search ID and put the product name and then search it. Then, I want to get the product price but there is where I get the error. Here is how the page looks:

Additionally, this is the HTML inspection of it:

My intention is to obtain the element inspected (see right part of the last photo) so I can then get the price. I have realized that when I use find_element using ID it gets the element right, but when I use the ClASS_NAME it doesn´t find it.
Here is the full code at the moment:
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from seleniumbase import Driver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver = Driver(uc=True)

driver.get("https://www.mediamarkt.es/")

############## Accept Cookies##############
input_element = driver.find_element(By.ID, "pwa-consent-layer-accept-all-button")
input_element.click()

############## Product Search ##############
input_element = driver.find_element(By.ID, "search-form")
input_element.send_keys("3HB4131X2" + Keys.ENTER)

############## Check Product ERROR HERE##############
input_element.clear()
input_element = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'sc-3f2da4f5-0 dievjx sc-b45c0335-2 fWUVlw')

So, my current approach is:
input_element = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'sc-3f2da4f5-0 dievjx sc-b45c0335-2 fWUVlw')
This is the Class Name of the "father". I´m expecting to get the element. However, it gives my the error that says that the element cannot be found.

sc-3f2da4f5-0 dievjx sc-b45c0335-2 fWUVlw these are multiple classes, not just one. So By.CLASS_NAME selector won't work.
Change this:
By.CLASS_NAME, 'sc-3f2da4f5-0 dievjx sc-b45c0335-2 fWUVlw'

To:
By.XPATH, "//span[@class='sc-3f2da4f5-0 dievjx sc-b45c0335-2 fWUVlw']"

Code:
input_element = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//span[@class='sc-3f2da4f5-0 dievjx sc-b45c0335-2 fWUVlw']")


Thank you! Really appreciated it. I was trying to use some XPath notation by since I´m still new with it too I wasn´t targeting it properly.
